# Ubuntu installation alongside windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

What happens if I select the option **Install Ubuntu alongside Windows7** during Ubuntu installation and in which drive Ubuntu will be installed? I have five partitions including C drive and System Reserved.

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu will be installed on a different partition and the Windows partition will not be affected. On but you will have the possibility to choose which OS start

Comment: 1.Can I use this option for installation?  does all the data in my hard disk

Comment: I always suggest to use `manual` method..you have alot more control on the partitions. Search around on what to do

Comment: 1.Does it affects any of  the data stored in the hard disk?   2.I have the following: 1.System reserved-100MB(primary partition) 2. C drive(primary partition: 54GB free) 3.D(primary partition: 48GB free)  4.G(logical drive: 35GB free)  5.I(logical drive: 46 GB free).      Where will the Ubuntu be installed?

Comment: you don't have some unused space? Ubuntu have to stay on his own partition..

Comment: No, I don't have unused space. How can I create it? Please help me.

Comment: You have to do a resize of the other partitions. The number 5..what are you using it for?

Comment: I have stored some media(videos and images) in that.

Comment: Then the simplest way is to move those file on another partition and then to install Ubuntu there

Comment: I have 135 GB of data in that drive. Can I try shrink option on that drive and then proceed or I must move all the data?

Comment: Yes you can..choose manual and then shrink that partition.. Create a new partition and install Ubuntu there

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any unused space, how do you think install a operating system? You must have some space! Add another hard disk to your system and install it over there. Or move you files to the extra hard disk and install ubuntu on the system hard disk. But, you must have some space to install Ubuntu. Since it's not a regular program it needs some space..